# Can work item attachments make TFS-DevOps database slow?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfs-workitem

I currently have more than 10000 work items in a Team Project. Users attach files directly to work items instead of using git repository, so there are about 2000 work items with attached files and this number could be quickly grow up. Do I have to discourage this practice? It could be make TFS-DevOps very slow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attachments are store in the TFS DB backend.  So if you take care of the DB (run regular maintenance, update statistics, reorder index, etc.) you should be fine.  Make sure the DB has plenty of memory and runs on fast disk.